# What do .txt files have to look like so that data can be read out of it?

Tags: io, fortran

I created a .txt file that looks like this

```
4 4 4 !DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
2 20  !DIM_START, DIM_END
```

But the point is that if I add now some comments like the Name of the Matrices that I use, then I get some errors, i.e.

```
4 4 4 !DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N
1 2 3 4 !A
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
1 2 3 4 !B
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
2 20  !DIM_START, DIM_END
```

it doesn't work any more. The Fortran file that I use to read the .txt file is

```
    ! OPEN FILE
    OPEN(UNIT=39, STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ',FILE='input.txt',IOSTAT=IERROR)
    !READ DIMENSIONS + CHECK IF SUCCESFUL
    READ(39,*,IOSTAT=IERROR)DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N
    ALLOCATE(A(DIM_M,DIM_L),B(DIM_L,DIM_N), C(DIM_M,DIM_N), STAT=IERROR)
    READ (39,*, IOSTAT=IERROR)A
    READ (39,*, IOSTAT=IERROR)B
    READ (39,*) DIM_START, DIM_END
    CLOSE(UNIT=39)
```

I left out all the parts where I check if reading the file worked (using IOSTAT). Any ideas how I could Change this?

Comment: What do you mean by *"some errors"*, you really should list the specific errors, we can't read your screen.

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: are those comments really needed? as you see, comment handling will add complexity to an otherwise clean and simple code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read it in as a string, then only use the part of the string up to the "!" for reading the variables.

Since you provided a non-compiling example, I will respond in kind.

```
! OPEN FILE
CHARACTER(LEN=132) :: ALine
CHARACTER(LEN=1), PARAMETER :: Bang '!'
OPEN(UNIT=39, STATUS='OLD', ACTION='READ',FILE='input.txt',IOSTAT=IERROR)
!READ DIMENSIONS + CHECK IF SUCCESsFUL
READ(39,*,IOSTAT=IERROR) ALine
IF(INDEX(ALine,bang) > 0) THEN
  READ(ALine(1:INDEX(ALine,'!')-1) ,*,IOSTAT=IERROR) DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N
ELSE
  READ(ALine ,*,IOSTAT=IERROR) DIM_M, DIM_L, DIM_N
ENDIF
ALLOCATE(A(DIM_M,DIM_L),B(DIM_L,DIM_N), C(DIM_M,DIM_N), STAT=IERROR)
!Etc
```

Comment: List directed formatting cannot be used to read a line of general text.

Comment: I'll have to check as I do this fairly regularly at work. I usually start with a search for commas and quotes, and break the string up into bite sized pieces, so you are probably right. I put it all in a library as I need to do it a couple times a year.

Answer (score 0):

If there are always DIM_M respectively DIM_L numbers on one line read them just in a loop

```
do l = 1, dim_l
  read(39,*,iostat=ierror) A(:,l)
  if (ierror /= 0) do something
end do

do n = 1, dim_n
  read(39,*,iostat=ierror) A(:,n)
  if (ierror /= 0) do something
end do
```